# make jQuery UI dialog not change it's position (relative to the browser) when scrolling browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

when I open a jQuyery UI dialog I can scroll the browser and the dialog would change it's position relative to the browser window, I want to make it stay in the same position relative to the browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UI dialog has the option `dialogClass`, where you can specify css classes which get added to the dialog style. So you can define a class like:

```
.dialogFixed {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

and call the Dialog like:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        dialogClass: 'dialogFixed'
    });
});
```

A `fixed` position should fit your requirements here.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/MpHN9/

(Well there is no css loaded so the dialog looks ugly, but notice the effect. Even if you scroll the window, the dialog remains in its position)